# Querying JSONB field on a associated model with Sequelize.js and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I have my two models `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` has a field `barId`, therefore has one `Bar` object associated with it.
I can query all my `Foo` objects and include their assiciated `Bar` object as so (I am using TypeScript with [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript)):

```
Foo.findAll<Foo>({
  include: [{ model: Bar }]
});
```

`Bar` object has a JSONB field `jsonb_field` with structure

```
{ inner_field1: 'some text', inner_field2: 'some more text' }
```

I can query `Bar` objects and filter by `inner_field1` as such:

```
Bar.findAll<Bar>({
  where: { 'jsonb_field': { inner_field1: 'text to find' } }
});
```

This produces following SQL query:

```
SELECT ... FROM "Bar" AS "Bar" 
WHERE ("Bar"."jsonb_field"#>>'{inner_field1}') = 'text to find'
```

So far so good. Now let's try querying `Foo` objects, include `Bar` objects and filtering by `inner_field1`:

```
Foo.findAll<Foo>({
  where: { '$bar.jsonb_field$': { inner_field1: 'text to find' } },
  include: [{ model: Bar }]
});
```

Now this throws an exception:

```
Error: Invalid value [object Object]
    at Object.escape ({project_root}\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sql-string.js:50:11)
    at Object.escape ({project_root}\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:917:22)
    at Object.whereItemQuery ({project_root}\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:2095:41)
    at _.forOwn ({project_root}\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-generator.js:1937:25)
    ...
```

For the record, I am including the Bar object correctly, because I can filter by other non-JSONB properties as such:

```
Foo.findAll<Foo>({
  where: { '$bar.number_field$': 5 },
  include: [{ model: Bar }]
});
```

As far as I know, the problem lies in Sequelize not being aware of the type of `jsonb_field` so it throws an error when an object is passed to the where query.

Is there a way around this error, maybe using `sequelize.literal()` or `sequelize.json()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sequelize.cast` and `$contains` operator:

```
Foo.findAll<Foo>({
  where: { '$bar.jsonb_field$': {
    $contains: sequelize.cast('{ "inner_field1": "text to find" }', 'jsonb')
  },
  include: [{ model: Bar }]
});
```

Or do it using `sequelize.literal` as you suggested:

```
Foo.findAll<Foo>({
  where: { '$bar.jsonb_field$': {
    $contains: sequelize.literal(`'{ "inner_field1": "text to find" }'::json`)
  },
  include: [{ model: Bar }]
});
```

Both solutions are vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), to make sure to escape or remove all characters that could cause problems (`"`,`'`,...)

Yes, I have just answered my own question. You are welcome.

Comment: It will work if you need to check for equality. But in case of [Op.Like], for example, it isn't helpful.

Comment: How would you do it if the `jsonb_field` object has more than just `inner_field1`, and you'd like to e.g. search for a `Foo` where `Bar.jsonb_field.inner_field2` is equal to `xyz`?

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize has better support for JSON columns nowadays, I think since v6, see https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/querying/json/

For example:

```js
FooModel.findAll({
  where: {
    'jsonb_field.inner_field': 'text to find',
  },
});
```

Or, when the inner field can be one of several options:

```js
FooModel.findAll({
  where: {
    'jsonb_field.inner_field': { [Op.in]: ['text to find', 'other text to find'] },
  },
});
```