# How to update the column in Sequelize Postgres DB for particular id with changing existing one using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

is there any possible way to update the data in a column for a particular id without changing the existing data, if it is possible to save it in DB, how to retrieve the data separately?

here I have used the `concat` method to save the data in a single column, is it the right way?

```
await stagesData.update(
      {
        stages_name: Sequelize.fn(
          "CONCAT",
          Sequelize.col("stages_name"),
          stages_name,
          ","
        ),
        stages_code: Sequelize.fn(
          "CONCAT",
          Sequelize.col("stages_code"),
          stages_code,
          ","
        ),
      },
      { where: { id: id } }
    );
```

if it is the right way how to retrieve the data separately? [by using an array or any other methods]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do? There are Array and JSONB Fields in Postgres, but maybe that could not be the right solution.

Comment: I'm trying to store multiple data for a particular id using the `concat` method. in a DB it stores data like `data1, data2, data3` in a single column and while retrieving  I get `"stages_name": "data1,data2,data3,",` like this  in postman., but I need the get the data in separately if I get the data separately it helps to display the data in separate card view for client-side

Comment: look if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421054/querying-jsonb-field-on-a-associated-model-with-sequelize-js-and-postgresql.